# What do we call classes which cannot be instantiated?

Tags: java, class

In Java their are some classes which can not be instantiated e.g. `java.util.Arrays` and `java.util.Collections`. Is ther any term for such classes which cannot be instantiated?

On the Wikipedia page for [Class (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Uninstantiable) they call such classes as **Uninstantiable classes**.

Comment: There may be multiple reason why you can't instantiate a class. For example Collections is an utility class, it cannot be instantiated because it simply provides static methods to help with collections. At the same time, an abstract class can't be instantiated either, but for a completely different reason (i.e. it should be extended and completed before). Hence if you really want to put them all in the same basket, I don't think you can really call them other than "uninstantiable" classes.

Comment: I would call them "utility classes", focusing more on what they are for rather than on the technicality of the fact they can't be instantiated.

Comment: The term "utility classes" seems to be commonly used to refer to classes that contain only static methods.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly alright question to ask here. It's concise, limited in scope, programming-related, shows its research. Huh.